# Getting Images from one page to show up on the following one

Tags: jquery, css, image, responsive

I am trying to get the image from a figure tag to show up on the next page using JQuery. Here's the code for JQuery that I've tried using:

```
(() => {
    $("a").click(function(){
        this.prev().appendTo('#product');
    })
});
```

Here's the figure tag:

```
<figure id="tennis_set">
    <img class="shop_image" src="images/shop2.jpg" >
    <a href="seemore.html"><figcaption id="tennis_set_no_shoes">See more</figcaption></a></figure>
```

Here's the div on the next page where I want it to go:

```
<div id="product_description_checkout">
                <h2 class="payment_title">Order Summary</h2>
                <div id="product"></div>
            </div>
```

So far it doesn't work. Am I going to have to use Ajax or PHP to store the data? Or am I just using the wrong code for JQuery?

Comment: Try storing it in localStorage, then retrieving it on the next page

Comment: Like this? I'm probably doing it wrong, but this didn't work either:

Comment: ```(() => {
    $("a").click(function(){
        setItem("image", JSON.stringify(this.prev()));
        getItem("image").appendTo("#product");
    })
});```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this. Set the image source as a variable into local storage. Then check for it on the next page. if its there, create an image element with the src from local storage.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let src = $(this).closest('figure').find('img').attr('src');
    console.log('src', src);
    localStorage.setItem("useImage", src);
    // now that we got it stored, allow the link to go through
    window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
  })
});

// on next page

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("useImage")) return;
  let img = $('<img />', {
    src: localStorage.getItem("useImage"),
  });
  img.appendTo($('#product'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="tennis_set">
  <img class="shop_image" src="images/shop2.jpg">
  <a href="seemore.html">
    <figcaption id="tennis_set_no_shoes">See more</figcaption>
  </a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: `Doesn't work` doesn't mean anything to anyone who cant see your code trying to execute in your browser. If you want assistance, try and determine if there is an error and or where things are breaking down - then post that

Comment: Sorry. You're right. Problem is, I'm not getting any error messages. What I can guess is that the previous code that was supposed to store the image url isn't doing that, but I don't know why.

Comment: Here's the code as it looks now: (() => {
    $("a").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("image", this.prev().attr('src'));
    });
});

//on next page

(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("image")) return;
    let img = $('<img />', {
        src: localStorage.getItem("image"),
    });
    img.appendTo($('#product'));
});

Comment: I discovered a typo in my code (I accidentally typed `this` instead of `$(this)`) - then I thought it might be better to reference the image from the `figure` container. Try the updated code and see if it helps. If it doesn't, try `console.log(localStorage('useImage'))` to see if the right data is getting stored

Comment: Here is the figure tag I'm trying to manipulate: 
  <figure id="tennis_set">
    <img class="shop_image" src="images/shop2.jpg" >
    <a href="seemore.html"><figcaption id="tennis_set_no_shoes">See more</figcaption></a>
  </figure>

Comment: OK, let me know if the updated answer helps...

Comment: I ran a console.log and, sure enough, the url hasn't been stored locally. Here is what it reads when I run console log after clicking the link: null;

Comment: The console log still doesn't show the image url.

Comment: Ok, jQuery and arrow functions aren't friends. Try the updated answer, which uses the good old $(document).ready() initialization. See if it captures the src

Comment: console.log(localStorage.getItem("useImage")); still says null and console.log('src', src) has no value. Javascript and JQuery are always painful.

Comment: Ah... well you can see it works in the snippet. The snippet will show errors because it doesn't like LocalStorage (causes errors in the sandbox)  - but you should be seeing that it is getting the SRC correctly. See if you can find why it works here, but not in your code